# Success/Fail variable in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is there a success/fail variable I can use in the SMTP Sampler that states whether or not a test was successful or had failures?

If there's not, what would be the best way to display that information in an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter has some [pre-defined properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) and among them:

> - **JMeterThread.last_sample_ok** - whether or not the last sample was OK - true/false. Note: this is updated after PostProcessors and Assertions have been run.

Example use case:

[image: JMeter If Controller on failure]

In above situation given `!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) condition, "SMTP Sampler" will be executed only if "Some Sampler" fails.